# Index columns with arithmetic operators

Tags: mysql, postgresql, index

I commonly make this query on my database
`SELECT * FROM Example_tab WHERE Column_a + Column_b < 10;`.

Is it possible to create indexes based on `Column_a + Column_b < 10` to speed up this lookup. I see it is possible to do it for oracle based db [over here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_indexing.htm) (by doing `CREATE INDEX Idx ON Example_tab(Column_a + Column_b);`).But I can't find it anywhere for postgresql or mysql.

Is it even possible to do it on databases other than oracle ? If yes, is it documented somewhere, what are they called (basically, what should I google to find them) ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936567/index-columns-with-arithmetic-operators#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PostgreSQL has **indexes on expressions** (since version 7 I think!), check the documentation: [Indexes on Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html).

So, you could easily add an index on `(column_a + column_b)`, with almost exactly the same syntax as in Oracle. The only difference would be the extra parentheses around the expression:

```
CREATE INDEX idx 
  ON Example_tab
  ((column_a + column_b)) ;
```

Note in case the above and the documentation isn't clear:
An **expression** can be as complicated as one wants and can include any number of operators or function calls.

---

MySQL does not have such indexes but they have a similar concept that can be used instead. MariaDB introduced [**`VIRTUAL`** (computed) columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) in their 5.2 version and the core MySQL just added them (called **`GENERATED`**) in their latest 5.7. See: [Generated columns in MySQL](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/).

So - in both MariaDB and MySQL - you can add a computed column and then an index on it. The syntax is similar but there are small differences. For **MariaDB**, the column can be either `VIRTUAL` or `PERSISTED`. If you want it indexed, it has to be `PERSISTED`:

```
ALTER TABLE Example_tab
   ADD COLUMN a_plus_b AS 
       (column_a + column_b) PERSISTED,
   ADD INDEX idx
       (a_plus_b) ;
```

For **MySQL** the column can be defined as either `VIRTUAL` or `STORED`. If you want it indexed, for versions before 5.7.8, it has to be `STORED`. For versions 5.7.8+ in can be either stored or not (in which case, the computed values are only stored once, in the index). See details on [Indexes on Virtual columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-secondary-indexes-virtual-columns):

```
ALTER TABLE Example_tab
   ADD COLUMN a_plus_b AS 
       (column_a + column_b),     -- optionally: STORED,
   ADD INDEX idx
       (a_plus_b) ;
```